# Get sum of every pair unique pair in the array

Tags: python

I am doing this array pair sum problem which says:
Given an integer array, output all the unique pairs that sum up to a specific value `k`.

So the input:

```
pair_sum([1,3,2,2],4)
```

would return 2 pairs:

```
(1,3)
(2,2)
```

Seems a pretty simple problem. This is what I my script looks like:

```
def pair_sum(arr,k):
    count =0
    l = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
            l.append((arr[i], arr[i+1]))
            y.append((arr[i-1],arr[i]))
    res = list(set(y+l))
    for i,j in res:
        if i + j == k:
            print (i,j)
            count +=1
    return count
```

And I is working fine with few test cases except this one:
`pair_sum([1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5,5,13,14,11,13,-1],10)`

My code is returning 5 but it should return 6. I know that this can be manually calculated and then I can check which pair is missing but what if the test case is sufficiently large. I can't check manually for each case.

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here because I might have considered almost every possible pair. Also, like what if I don't want to use `set` here like can there be a more general solution which is not specific to any language. Because how can you get unique pair without using `set`?

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `for i in range(len(arr-1)): for j in range(i, len(arr)): if arr[i]+arr[j]==k: print((i,j))`?

Comment: It looks like your code is only summing up *adjacent* numbers?

Comment: @Aran-Fey exactly. This requires a different approach that should take all the numbers into consideration. But than it would take O(n^2). I was looking for O(n)

Comment: `itertools.combinations(arr, r=2)` will iteratively generate all the possible combinations of pairs of the numbers in `arr`.

Comment: @martineau It will work but will fail for the following test case `[1,2,3,1],3)` for which it should output 1 but will give 2 . Anyway I found a way around of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is I added the elements to the set and took the difference between my sum and the element of list. If difference is in my set then I paired them

```
def pair_sum(arr,k):
count = 0
seen  = set()
output = set()
for i in arr:
    num = k - i
    if num not in seen:
        seen.add(i)
    else:
         output.add( (num,i) )
return len(output)
```

Comment: If you're going to participate here, you need to learn how to properly format/indent the Python code you post.

Comment: This would fail for repetitive cases like [1,2,3,2,2,2]

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for the efficiency of this, but:

```
[(x,y) 
 for (i,x) in enumerate(arr) 
 for (j,y) in enumerate(arr) 
 if i < j and x+y == k]
```

Just loop over all pairs, keeping only those whose first element comes before the second so as to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `pairwise()` recipe shown in the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) as shown below.

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def pair_sum(arr, k):
    for pair in (pair for pair in pairwise(arr) if sum(pair) == k):
        print(pair)

pair_sum([1, 3, 2, 2], 4)
print()
pair_sum([1, 2, 3, 1], 3)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3)
(2, 2)

(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def aps(arr, k):
    if len(arr)<2:
        return False

    seen = set()
    output = set()
    for num in arr:
        target = k - num
        if target not in seen:
            seen.add(num)
        else:
            output.add((min(num,target), max(num,target)))
    print(output)
    print(seen)
    return len(output)
```

Comment: its recommended to explain even with minimal explanation of an answer unless the code is self explainable.